# meminfo doesn't include memory allocated by page_allocator

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I found that the meminfo doesn't show the memory usage which is directly allocated by the page allocator (fn:allocate_pages)

```
file:///proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        2039496 kB
MemFree:          108684 kB
MemAvailable:      79108 kB
Buffers:             104 kB
Cached:           375520 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:           403632 kB
Inactive:          30588 kB
Active(anon):     403548 kB
Inactive(anon):    30544 kB
Active(file):         84 kB
Inactive(file):       44 kB
Unevictable:      218488 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:                 0 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        277080 kB
Mapped:           132144 kB
Shmem:            157012 kB
Slab:              55540 kB
SReclaimable:       8276 kB
SUnreclaim:        47264 kB
KernelStack:        2848 kB
PageTables:        23364 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     1019748 kB
Committed_AS:   17172160 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
Percpu:              304 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
Hugetlb:               0 kB
DirectMap4k:       34644 kB
DirectMap2M:     2062336 kB
DirectMap1G:           0 kB
```

Is there any way to know the size of the page allocated memory?

Comment: How have you determined that this memory is not included in meminfo?